# differentiating between data with $.get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

Say I have a php page Data2.php that is echoing 2 numbers. For example 23443 and 4. And so the php page just looks like this:

```
234434
```

and I want $.get to differentiate each of the numbers. How could I do this?

for example:

```
 $.get("Data2.php", function (firstnumber) {
 });

 $.get("Data2.php", function (secondnumber) {
 });
```

---

I have thought about echoing them into divs and things like that. But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This can be done at your PHP side. Push each number into an array and `echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: If it's only 2 numbers, and always only 2 numbers, you can use a delimiter to separate the data. Ex. `23443,4`, but of course, if your data is getting complex, it would be good to use a datatype that is easy to read from both PHP and JavaScript, such as JSON, XML, HTML.

Comment: it is only ever 2 numbers! What is a delimiter @DaveChen ?

Comment: If you're only going to be using 2 numbers, you may separate them with a comma, space, or character(s) of your choosing. Such as from the above, `23443,4` would be the output of the PHP file, and you would be able to use `number.split(',')` to get both the numbers without making two requests.

Comment: As Dave said, you can use a delimiter. Echo 23443,4, and use string.split(',') to get an array that contains 23443,4. Read about split: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the response as a [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) array like:

```
$response= array('first'=>23443, 'second'=>4);

echo json_encode($response);
```

And in AJAX ,

```
$.get("Data2.php", function (response) {
   var firstnum  = response.first,
       secondnum = response.second;
   alert(firstnum + ', '+ secondnum);
},"json");
```

Comment: Should I be getting a result NULL?

Comment: Yes! I have been staring at it for ages. I can't work out why it doesn't work!

Comment: I have replaced `23443` and `4` with two php $

Comment: Do you get any response, check out you firebug console

Comment: You made two spelling mistakes